# Getting AuthenticationCredentials.SecurityTokenResponse from CRM for Kerberos validation

Tags: c#, crm, kerberos

I'm trying to figure out a different way one can get the SecurityTokenResponse from Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.AuthenticationCredentials to be used when calling CRM service with Kerberos authentication.

Currently I only have the one working scenario where I manually send in the username and password:

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Discovery;

IServiceManagement<IDiscoveryService> serviceManagement = ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateManagement<IDiscoveryService>(new Uri("https://crm.myCrmSite.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc"));
AuthenticationCredentials authCreds = new AuthenticationCredentials();

authCreds.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = _userName;
authCreds.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = _password;

AuthenticationCredentials tokenCredentials = serviceManagement.Authenticate(authCreds);
SecurityTokenResponse securityTokenR = tokenCredentials.SecurityTokenResponse;
```

How can I get the SecurityTokenResponse for the user executing the application (the WindowsIdentity user)instead of having to manually type in username and password?